# Multiplying the remaining balance of an amount

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to multiply the total of an array of cells, but only want to multiply the remaining number of the overage amount.

For example:

```
Goal amount: 10,000
Sum: 15,000
Multiply by: 5,000
```

Comment: Is the overage computed for the total value of the array or for each cell of the array?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to multiply the `Sum` of an array of cells by the value of the overage amount.

If my understanding is correct, this sort of thing could be done using a formula like the one below:

```
sum*(sum-goal)
```

So, using the values provided in your question, this would look like:

```
Goal amount: 10,000
Sum: 15,000
Multiply by: 5,000

15,000*(15,000-10,000)
```

Which could be simplified to:

```
15,000*(5,000)
```

This would give you the result of:

```
75,000,000
```

Best of luck and I hope this helped you!